# Как узнать установленный язык на Windows?

Tags: c#, wpf

Хочу узнать язык, которой стоит на Windows у пользователя. Как это можно сделать? Есть ли библиотека, или куда обратиться в системе?

CultureInfo - здесь не очень подходит, он показывает региональные параметры.

Насчёт регистра. У меня стоит Win 10 на английском (изначально был на русском)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если доставать значения из регистра, то InstallLanguage почему-то с кодом 0419 (ru-Ru).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть InstallLanguageFallback со значением en-Us. Но не получается достать, это значение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
const string path = @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Language";
using RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(path);
string value = key.GetValue("InstallLanguage") as string;
if (int.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out int lcid))
{
  CultureInfo info = new CultureInfo(lcid);
  Console.WriteLine(info.DisplayName);
  Console.WriteLine(info.IetfLanguageTag);
}
```

Вывод:

```
Russian (Russia)
ru-RU
```

Возможно проблема в особенность моей ОС.

Comment: Есть язык дистрибутива, есть текущий активный пакет MUI, вас что именно интересует?

Comment: @aepot у меня проект на WPF и хочу, чтобы при первом открытии ставился сразу нужный язык. Можете пожалуйста поподробней рассказать, что вы перечислили

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.installeduiculture)

```
CultureInfo systemCulture = CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture;
```

Если нужно узнать не язык дистрибутива, а текущий MUI, то попробуйте получить значение из реестра

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Language\
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример кода

```
const string path = @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Language";
using RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(path);
string value = key.GetValue("InstallLanguage") as string;
if (int.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out int lcid))
{
    CultureInfo info = new CultureInfo(lcid);
    Console.WriteLine(info.DisplayName);
    Console.WriteLine(info.IetfLanguageTag);
}
```

Вывод в консоль (у меня английский язык системы)

```
English (United States)
en-US
```

---

Из REG_MULTI_SZ строку можно получить так

```
string lang = (key.GetValue("InstallLanguageFallback") as string[])?.FirstOrDefault(x => x?.Length > 0);
```

Comment: Не помогло, у меня стоит английский язык, но ```systemCulture``` выводит, что у меня русский.

Comment: @MilkRen у вас английский дистрибутив стоит или русский, а потом после установки язык изменён на английский?

Comment: Изначально был русский, потом изменён на английский

Comment: @MilkRen поэтому русский и выводит. Ща ещё поищу, но не уверен что в рамках Win32 API есть способ это объехать.

Comment: @MilkRen дополнил ответ.

Comment: если брать значение из InstallLanguage, то показывает код 0419 (русский язык). Есть  InstallLanguageFallback (значение en-US) из него значение взять не могу. Получаю ```System.String[]```. Подскажешь, как получить значение ?

Comment: Вывести этот массив через for, foreach, string.Join не получается

Comment: @MilkRen код мне надо угадать?

Comment: Я однажды писал для этой ветки реестра небольшой код. В ней указывается идентификатор культуры, так называемый LCID. Для того, чтоб по нему получить культуру, надо сначала в `int`, как HEX число прочитать (что-то вроде этого `int.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out var lcid)`), а затем уже делать культуру `var culture = new CultureInfo(lcid);` и делать с ней все, что надо. А если надо наоборот туда записать значение, то `culture.LCID.ToString("X4")`.

Comment: @MilkRen удалось разобраться?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я не совсем понимаю, что я должен вложить в ```value```? Можете пожалуйста рассказать поподробнее

Comment: @aepot Прошу прощения, я тогда отошёл. Я использовал ```RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(keyPath);``` и потом ```string value = key.GetValue("InstallLanguageFallback").ToString();```

Comment: @MilkRen дополнил ответ

Comment: @aepot Спасибо большое за помощь, думаю на других системах будет работать корректно.(к сожалению, проверить у себя не смогу) Я сверху дополнил.

Comment: @aepot Всё добро! И снова большое спасибо!

Comment: @MilkRen REG_MULTI_SZ - `string lang = (key.GetValue("InstallLanguageFallback") as string[])?.FirstOrDefault(x => x?.Length > 0);`

Comment: @aepot Всё супер! Получилось! Вывело правильно